# Laravel eloquent collection can't loop in view blade.php

Tags: laravel-5.6

**Model:products:**

```
public function category() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\categories','categories_id');
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/showproducts',function () {    
    return view('admin.showproducts', [
        'mydata' => App\products::with('category')->get()
        ]);
});
```

**View :showproducts:**

```
<table>     <!-- Added by edit -->
    @foreach($mydata as $product)
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">{{$count++}}</th>
            <td>{{$product->pro_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$product->pro_code}}</td>
            <td>{{$product->price}}</td>

            <td>{{$product->category->category_name}}</td>

            <td ><img src="{{url('/myimages')}}/{{$product->pro_img}}" style="width:80px; height: 60px;"></td>
            <td><a href="{{url('/editproduct')}}/{{$product->id}}" class="btn btn-fill btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a>  |
                <a href="{{url('/')}}" class="btn btn-fill btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</a>
            </td>    
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

I want to echo the `category_name` field, but it does not show on the view. While retrieving in collection, all is OK. The only problem is to iterate

```
<td>{{$product->category->category_name}}</td>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It's ok i found the solution the problem was i am getting collection and collection have an array so now this way i got solution. <td> {{$product->category['category_name']]}}<td>